# "dirCount" not working correctly

Tags: c, linux, directory

I'm trying to count the number of directories at a given path, but it seems to not be working correctly for some reason.

```
DIR *dir;       //directory to read from
struct dirent *dr;  //directory entry
int dirCount = 0;   //count of subdirectories in directory

if(path == NULL)
{
    perror("path = null");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if(chdir(path) == -1)
{
    perror("chdir failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if((dir = opendir(path)) == NULL) //open directory
{
    perror("opendir() error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

while((dr = readdir(dir)) != NULL)  //loop to check if leaf
{
    while((strcmp(dr -> d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dr ->  d_name, "..") == 0) && dr != NULL)   //skip "." and ".."
    {
        dr = readdir(dir);
    }

    if(dr -> d_type == DT_DIR)
    {
        dirCount++;
    }
}
return dirCount;
}
```

This is the code, but it seems that when I run it on the certain file for my homework assignment (even though there is only 1 .txt file in the path) it always returns 2, and I'm not sure why. When using ls -la on the same file it only outputs ".", "..", and the .txt file.

I have tried this on other files and it seems to work, but for some reason isn't working for the specific directory I'm supposed to be using it on, and I can't think of why.

Comment: Disregard, seems to be working now.

Comment: Are you trying to count directories or files? Your first paragraph says *"I'm trying to count the number of directories at a given path," but later you say *"(even though there is only 1 .txt file in the path) it always returns 2"*

Comment: Directories. It should have been returning 0 they way I thought about it. Pointed out the .txt file in case there was some black magic going on.

Comment: "Working" seems a matter of opinion here. You never [close the directory object you opened](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/closedir.html). Sooner or later that is going to become a problem.

Answer (score 0):

check `dr!=NULL` condition before checking `dr->d_name` as suggested by other. And instead of 2nd `while loop` you can use `if` statement.

```
while((dr = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {    
                if(dr!=NULL && (strcmp(dr -> d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dr ->  d_name, "..") == 0)) {
                        dr = readdir(dir);
                        continue;
                }
                if(dr -> d_type == DT_DIR) {
                        dirCount++;
                }
 }
```

Comment: The second `while` is fine, a bit unorthodox instead of just having your `if` followed by a `continue`, but nothing particularly wrong with it.

Comment: ya that's true @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: just thought of something, does git hide directory files if you clone a repository? It seems to not work until I get out of the repository folders, and then it works fine.

Comment: Place the `dr != NULL` check before you evaluate `dr->d_name`